# Exception on startup: NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>()

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I tried to update Spring Kafka version but got exception

- Spring Kafka version 2.3.4.RELEASE
- Spring Boot version 2.2.2.RELEASE
- Kafka-clients version 2.3.1

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    ... 102 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show you code and configuration and the full stack trace (you should never edit/truncate stack traces here). The error seems quite clear:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.()

There is no no-arg constructor - it needs a producer factory; we need to see the code and configuration to figure out who's trying to create a template with no PF.

Normaly, Spring Boot will automatically configure a `KafkaTemplate` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! The problem wa in the tests - I incorrectly determined the generic type of KafkaTemplate. I used 
`KafkaTemplate <String, Bytes>` instead of `KafkaTemplate<String, Message>` which  I am using in app code. So I suppose, test spring context could not define proper bean to autowire.